# Scanner file read returning scanner.hasNext() as false

Tags: java, windows, file, java.util.scanner

I have the following code to compare two files, being read using Scanner:

```
private boolean fileCompare(String fileOutput, String fileSolution)throws IOException{
       Scanner scanOutput = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileOutput)));
       Scanner scanSolution = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileSolution)));

       System.out.println(scanOutput.hasNext()); ---> returning false
       System.out.println(scanSolution.hasNext()); ---> returning true
}
```

The files `fileOutput` and `fileSolution` are identical in content. The only difference is how they are created. fileOutput is created as `java Program1 > fileOutput.txt` (in Windows command line) and the file `fileSolution` is created manually.

`scanOutput.hasNext())` is returning `false`, but this file has content in it.

Comment: what is the content of the file?. Strings? numbers?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you open `fileOutput` please?

Comment: The file contains both strings and numbers.

Comment: Looks like the file doesn't have any content when being checked by the `Scanner` or you're passing a nonexistent path.

Comment: @Dropout Can you please explain what do you mean by open the file? The file is getting created in the windows command line (inside Java program I am using ProcessBuilder to create it). fileOutput is a string parameter for the method above containing the filename with the path.

Comment: @kajarigd ah, my bad. was reading too quickly.

Comment: @kajarigd - Please show us the content of your file and the values of "String fileOutput, String fileSolution"

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I am passing the correct path. Scanner is not giving any "path not specified" error. The file has content. I can see the content directly from command line.

Comment: Maybe you can see the content but the code that tries to read the file is executed before the code that creates the file, thus the `Scanner` cannot find it.

Comment: fileOutput: output\User_K\Program5_0.txt